# What's wrong with my configuration of sonata admin for menu grouping?

Tags: admin, configure, sonata

I'm programming my own website with symfony 4.2.8 and it's bundle, that is sonata admin. At First, I had installed the symfony and it's bundle sonata amdin. And according to configuration guides, I configured sonata admin bundle. Everything is ok until I configure dashboard groups. I don't know What is my fault in my configuration.

> Error Message : An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template ("Admin service "sonata.admin.user" not found in admin pool. Did you mean "app.admin.user" or one of those: []?").

http://enagape.net/admin/dashboard

My configuration is like these.

in config/packages/sonata_admin.yaml.

```
sonata_admin:
    #persist_filters: true
    #filter_persister: filter_persister_service_id
    title: 'Sonata Admin'
    dashboard:

            blocks:
                    # display two dashboard blocks
                    -
                            position: left
                            type: sonata.admin.block.admin_list
                            settings:
                                    groups: [users, pages, blog]

            groups:
                    users:
                            label: Users
                            label_catalogue: ~
                            items:
                                    - sonata.admin.user
#                                        - sonata.admin.group

                    pages:
                            label: Pages
                            label_catalogue: ~
                            items:
#                                        - sonata.admin.page
#                                        - sonata.admin.site

                    blog:
                            label: Blog
                            label_catalogue: ~
                            items:
                                    - sonata.admin.post
#                                        - sonata.admin.comment
#                                        - sonata.admin.category
#                                        - sonata.admin.tag
sonata_block:
    blocks:
            sonata.admin.block.admin_list:
                    contexts: [admin]
```

And in config/services.yaml.

```
parameters:
    locale: 'en'

services:
    # default configuration for services in *this* file
    _defaults:
        autowire: true      # Automatically injects dependencies in your services.
        autoconfigure: true # Automatically registers your services as commands, event subscribers, etc.

    # makes classes in src/ available to be used as services
    # this creates a service per class whose id is the fully-qualified class name
    App\:
        resource: '../src/*'
        exclude: '../src/{DependencyInjection,Entity,Migrations,Tests,Kernel.php}'

    # controllers are imported separately to make sure services can be injected
    # as action arguments even if you don't extend any base controller class
    App\Controller\:
        resource: '../src/Controller'
        tags: ['controller.service_arguments']

    # add more service definitions when explicit configuration is needed
    # please note that last definitions always *replace* previous ones

    # <Entity>Admin class
    App\Admin\:
        resource: '../src/Admin'

    # for user
    app.admin.user:
        class: App\Admin\UserAdmin
        arguments:
            - ~
            - App\Entity\User
            - ~
        tags:
            -
                name: sonata.admin
                manager_type: orm
                label: User
                group: users
                #filter_persister: filter_persister_service_id


    # for post
    app.admin.post:
        class: App\Admin\PostAdmin
        arguments:
            - ~
            - App\Entity\Post
            - ~
        tags:
            -
                name: sonata.admin
                manager_type: orm
                label: Post
                group: blog
                #filter_persister: filter_persister_service_id
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution to configure sonata admin. This is best way to make wonderful admin.
After installation of sonata admin bundle, you can use symfony console.

For example,

```
php bin/console make:sonata:admin
```

That's it, you just enter the upper command line.